pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The resolution lifetime expired after 21.215 seconds
When I'm trying to connect to pymongo getting below error
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The resolution lifetime expired after 21.215 seconds: Server 192.168.1.1 UDP port 53 answered The DNS operation timed out.; It was working fine before my system got upgraded to windows 11
below is my code
from pymongo import MongoClient
mongouri = "mongodb+srv://******.net/
cnxn = MongoClient(mongouri)

Even i changed my DNS server to google DNS (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4) still same error
I'm using python==3.8 pymongo==3.11.0 & dnspython==2.2.1

You seem to be facing a DNS resolution issue when trying to connect to your MongoDB instance with pymongo. Here are a few things you can do to solve the problem.

See MongoDB URI

Make sure your mongouri is properly formatted. It looks like this:
#Processing Python
mongouri = "mongodb+srv://username:password@clustername.mongodb.net/dbname?retry type=true&w=most".
Replace username, password, clustername, and dbname with your actual credentials.


update pymongo and dnspython .

Using pymongo==3.11.0 and dnspython==2.2.1. Try to update yourself to the latest version:
pip install --up pymongo dnspython

Now pymongo==4.x.x and dnspython==2.x.x are the latest versions. Upgrades can address assembly issues.




Check DNS settings .

You mentioned that you changed your DNS server to Google DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4). Make sure you use these settings properly.
Also you can try flushing your DNS cache:

On Windows:
ipconfig /flushdns
On macOS/Linux:
sudo dscacheutil -input; sudo killall -HUP mDNSresponder






Check network connectivity .

Make sure your machine can connect to the MongoDB server. Try to ping the IP address or domain of the MongoDB server.
Check if there are any firewall rules or network issues that are blocking the connection.




I think if OP wanted an AI generated answer, they'd just go to ChatGPT or CoPilot...
